# How do I only build the jar-WITHOUT-dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm compiling Kotlin(JRE) and deploying it to a little robot.  I've had very good luck creating a jar-with-dependencies, thank you StackOverflow.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>${project.main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But the jar is BIG, like 25mb big.  The jar without the dependencies is a totally sane 26kb, which really makes a difference because packaging up that big JAR is slow, then I have to `scp` deploy it to the bot every time.

**I was able to preload all the dependencies into a folder on the bot**, via `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and copying them over. (again, thank you StackOverflow).  Now I need an easy way to set a property that will make it JUST compile and copy the `target/MYBOT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and not bother trying to compile the `target/MYBOT-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the property `<assembly.skipAssembly>` to `true` (in the `<properties>` section of your POM). Then the `jar-with-dependencies` will not be built.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I want!  I tried (see https://gist.github.com/salamanders/acb1ffddaf0c70705d27f64a7e605c00#file-pom-xml-L27 ), and it doesn't seem to do anything different when I do a `mvn deploy` (it still builds both jars), but if you can spot what I messed up, this sounds perfect.

Comment: Found it.  Also added in the plugin conf `<skipAssembly>${assembly.skipAssembly}</skipAssembly>` and it worked, thank you so much!